# Save and reuse a Facebook access token in Unity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty sure this has to be a simple thing to do but I can't figure it out...
I call FB.LogInWithReadPermissions which logs the user in fine. I get the access token and expiration and store them. Next time the user loads our app, we want to use their previous access token but can't figure out how. 
I make a call to initialize Facebook:

```
FB.Init(FB.AppId, AccessToken)
```

but then if I call

```
FB.API("/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture,languages,gender,location, HttpMethod.GET, (IGraphResult meResult) => { }
```

It fails with

```
 {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"******"}}
```

I thought calling Init with the previous access token would work to set the access token on FB but I guess I was wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After calling `FB.Init` verify `FB.IsLoggedIn`

Comment: After calling FB.Init passing it the access token, FB.IsLoggedIn and FB.IsInitialized are always false. I also have the onInitComplete complete set during the Init call and it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

You must to check init and login process all time you came back to app:

```
    public void init(string s = "") 
    {

        if (!FB.IsInitialized) 
        {
            FB.Init(SetInint);
        } else 
        {
            SetInint();
        }

    }



    private void SetInint()
    {
        if(!FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
                    FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(  new List<string>(){"public_profile","email","user_friends","publish_actions"}, LogginFinish);
        }
                else 
        {
                    FB.API("/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture,languages,gender,location, HttpMethod.GET, (IGraphResult meResult) => { }
        }
}
```

Comment: I thought that with the access token the user doesn't have to login every time.